# Plot solution of ODE with singularity

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I wish to plot the solution of the following ODE:

```
T = 1;
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == Boole[X[t]<= 0]  - Boole[X[t] > 0], X[0] == x}, X, {t, 0, T}, {x}];
Show[
 Table[
  ParametricPlot[{Y[x][t], t}, {t, 0, T}],
  {x, -1,1,0.1}
  ],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}
 ]
```

But the code does not compute: I'm guessing because the characteristic accumulate at zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
Simplify[Boole[X[t]<= 0]  - Boole[X[t] > 0]]
```

> `Piecewise[{{-1, X[t] > 0}}, 1]`

So we can simplify ODE and get the plottable solution:

```
T = 1;
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == Piecewise[{{-1, X[t] > 0}}, 1], 
   X[0] == x}, X, {t, 0, T}, {x}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[Y[x][t], {x, -1, 1, 0.1}]], {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: That's very nice. Thank you.